# Get all unique authors that have made commits which are ahead of development for a branch

Tags: git, github, git-bash

So I am wanting to get all authors which have edited a branch. And hence I want to get a list of all people that have made commits ahead of development in x branch.

I currently get a list of all commits that are ahead by doing

```
git rev-list --left-right origin/development...origin/OtherBranch | grep '>' |cut -c2-
```

And then for each commit I run

```
git show $commitID
```

And parse the username and email out of that result for unique names/emails
I was wondering if there was a better way to do all this for instance I know I can grab total commits names directly running

```
git log -n 100 --format=\"%ae, %an\" --no-merges $branchName | sort -u
```

but this does all commits not just those ahead as well as not unique

Comment: If the commit range you get with your `rev-list` is ok, why use just `$branchName` for your log? Did you try `git log -n 100 --format=\"%ae, %an\" --no-merges  --left-right origin/development...origin/OtherBranch | sort -u` ? That being said, for the range, I'd have suggested simply doing `git log --format=\"%ae, %an\" origin/development..origin/OtherBranch | sort -u` (mind the two dots, not three, since we don't want the symetric diff here)

Comment: Using 3 dots it seems to show commits  ahead and behind dev, with 2 dots its giving me expected result.
Can you explain what this difference is? Does 2 dots simply mean to focus on those ahead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using double dots and combining commands as mentioned by RomainValeri

resultant command is

```
git log --format="%ae, %an" --no-merges $targetBranch..$branchName | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`--ancestry-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-path) option of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)<sup>1</sup> to get the list of commits between `development` and `OtherBranch`.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-path):

> When given a range of commits to display (e.g. `commit1..commit2` or `commit2 ^commit1`), only display commits that exist directly on the ancestry chain between the `commit1` and `commit2`, i.e. commits that are both descendants of `commit1`, and ancestors of `commit2`.

In your case, you would say:

```sh
git log --ancestry-path origin/development..origin/OtherBranch
```

Notice the use of the [*double dot notation*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_double_dot) to select the commits that are *not reachable* from `origin/development` but that are *reachable* from `origin/OtherBranch`.

You can then combine this with the [`--format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---formatltformatgt) option to print just the author's email and name:

```sh
git log --ancestry-path --format="%ae, %an" origin/development..origin/OtherBranch
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You could also use [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) here, since it accepts much of the same options as `git log`.